# php artisan make:auth not defined in laravel 8.49

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i tried to put

```
php artisan make:auth
```

but it came out this:

```
  Command "make:auth" is not defined.  

  Did you mean one of these?
      make:cast
      make:channel
      make:command
      make:component
      make:controller
      make:event
      make:exception
      make:factory
      make:job
      make:listener
      make:mail
      make:middleware
      make:migration
      make:model
      make:notification
      make:observer
      make:policy
      make:provider
      make:request
      make:resource
      make:rule
      make:seeder
      make:test
```

is there a new command similar to make:auth or something? thank you in advance

Comment: Use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze or https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-jetstream instead.

Comment: thank you for replying. after i install breeze/jetstream, then i can run the same command?

Comment: No, the command is not working anymore

Answer (score 2):

for working of make:auth you need to install the laravel/ui package,For more insfo you can check that documentation https://github.com/laravel/ui...But as
@Parsa_Gholipour suggests try to use jetstream ...You will get better support in the laravel 8